# PHP: undefined index error but variable has correct value when printed

Tags: php, android

I'm passing some values from an android app to a PHP script. I get an undefined index error in my PHP script but the variables have the correct values when I print them out from within the script. I want these errors gone but I can't figure out why they are there in the first place. Here is how they are passed to the PHP script.

**Java Code**

```
//build url data to be sent to server
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));

String result = "";
InputStream is = null;
//http post
try{
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/PasswordCheck.php");
  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"utf-8"));
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
  is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
  Log.e("Connection", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("drop-in") or die("database not found");

if(isset($_POST["username"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
}
if(isset($_POST["password"])){
    $suppliedPassword = $_POST["password"];
}

$databasePassword = "";
$output = "false";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Username = '$username'") or die("query failed");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
    $databasePassword = $row['password'];
    if($databasePassword == $suppliedPassword)
    {
        $output = "true";
    }
}
    print($output);
    mysql_close();

?>
```

EDIT: added PHP script (they aren't in the same file, the code tags are misbehaving)

Comment: Could you post your PHP script?

Comment: Check your case. In your query you have `Password` but then you are trying to pull it from the result with `$row['password']`. PHP array keys are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks mate. That fixed it. Strikes me as an odd error to generate. It was saying the problem was right at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a simple spelling error. I used a lower case 'p' in the word 'password' in my loop instead of an uppercase. Odd that it caused the error that it did.